# failed to open stream permission denied - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hace unos días instale Telescope para Laravel, y desde entonces todos los días me devuelve este error.

```
The stream or file "var/www/proyecto/storage/logs/laravel-2021-03-03.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream permission denied
```

Es como que todos los días cuando se genera un fichero nuevo de log, telescope tiene que poder acceder a el, pero todos los días tengo que hacer esto.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Esto no es normal que todos los días tenga que que habilitar permisos a la carpeta, que puedo hacer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: me salté lo básico, el por qué.

#### Por qué pasa?

Usualmente el webserver y el proceso fast-cgi operan como el usuario `www-data` y el grupo de igual nombre. Cuando un request web deja registro en los logs, ese es el usuario que escribe en el archivo. Por el contrario, si un usuario (ej ubuntu) ejecuta un comando por consola él es quien escribe en los logs.

Dado que la configuración de los logs tuvieran el driver `daily` configurado como

```
   'daily' => [
       'driver' => 'daily',
       'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log')
    ]
```

Pensemos que existe **una ruta que escribe en los logs**:

```
# routes/web.php

Route::get('/log', function() {
  app('log')->info('test request');
});
```

Un request que escribiera en los logs generaría un archivo con dueño www-data

```
 # curl http://127.0.0.1/log
 # ls -al storage/logs

 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   141 mar  5 20:46 laravel-2021-03-05.log
```

Mientras que al ejecutar **un comando que escribe en los logs**

```
# routes/console.php

Artisan::command('log', function (): void {
    app('log')->info('test command');
});
```

se generaría un archivo cuyo dueño es ubuntu (el usuario que ejecuta el comando, me refiero)

```
 # php artisan log
 # ls -al storage/logs

 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu   ubuntu    142 mar  6 00:11 laravel-2021-03-06.log
```

El comportamiento por defecto es crear el archivo con permisos 0644, o sea: "el dueño puede leer y escribir, el resto solamente leer". Lo que equivale a que ya sea www-data o ubuntu, el que genere el archivo provocará que el otro no pueda escribir hasta que tú manualmente le cambies el dueño y/o permisos al archivo.

(si el usuario ubuntu está corriendo el servidor de desarrollo `php artisan serve` todo se escribiría con su usuario)

#### Posibles Soluciones

**1. Cambiar permisos en `config/logging.php`.**

El permiso por defecto ya vimos que es 0644. Tú puedes definir otro permiso específico.

```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'permission' => 0666
    ]
```

666 significa que todos pueden leer y escribir.

**2. Añadir el usuario actual al grupo** `www-data`

Si no se quiere dejar el archivo públicamente escribible, puede asignarse permiso `0664` y añadir el usuario al mismo grupo que php-fpm.

```
   sudo usermod -aG $USER  www-data
```

Pero habría que hacer lo mismo añadiendo a www-data al grupo del usuario (cosa que parece peor remedio que la enfermedad)

```
   sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

**3. Correr el servicio php-fpm como el usuario ubuntu**

Si el webserver actuase como el usuario ubuntu entonces todos los logs serían de éste, sin conflicto de permisos. Sin embargo **esta es una
pésima idea**. ¿Por qué correrías el webserver como un usuario sudoer? Al revés, vean el punto 4

**4. Correr comandos como www-data**

En vez de darle más privilegios al webserver tiene más sentido ejeutar los comandos con un usuario de menos privilegios. El comando inicial podría correrse como:

```
 sudo -u www-data php artisan log
```

Para ahorrarse la verborrea, es más eficiente hacer un alias para el comando. En tu archivo `.bash_aliases` por ejemplo

```
 alias artisanwww="sudo -u www-data php artisan"
```

Y luego

```
 artisanwww log
```

Los logs generados serían para todo efecto propiedad del mismo usuario que el webserver.

Comment: Hola @ffflabs gracias por tu respuesta, pero me gustaria saber que es lo que sucede, todo esto por instalar Telescope?? por que sucede que no se visualiza la web ni usuarios invitado ni registrados?? Todo es por lo mismo? agradeceria a poder ser una explicación de por que pasa. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Solo estoy respondiendo el tema de los logs, pero cuéntame eso sí, que owner y group tienen los logs que tirar error, antes de que les rectifiques el permiso?

Comment: No entendi lo último que dices en el comentario, por otro lado don de `single` en que archivo se realiza!??

Comment: En config/logs.php tienes que añadir permission 0666 a los logs, más que en single en tu caso en daily. Te pregunté quién aparece como dueño de los archivos cuando te sale el error, antes de correr los comandos con que hoy lo reparas